# Wrong columns when reading csv data from a DB as DataFrames with python, but right columns when executin in jupiter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, sqlalchemy

I have a table in my DB which have 8 columns, 1 for id and 7 storing csv data in binary as BLOB, I read the csv data, unpickle it and save each of the 7 csv columns in one panda dataframe.

My code is the following:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')
metadata_obj = MetaData()
metadata_obj.reflect(bind=engine)
Tabla1 = Table('Tabla1', metadata_obj, autoload_with=engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

query1= session.query(Tabla1).filter_by(idCliente=2).all()

for i in query1:

    df1=pd.DataFrame(pickle.loads(i.df1))
    df2=pd.DataFrame(pickle.loads(i.df2))
    df3=pd.DataFrame(pickle.loads(i.df3))
    df4=pd.DataFrame(pickle.loads(i.df4))
    df5=pd.DataFrame(pickle.loads(i.df5))
    df6=pd.DataFrame(pickle.loads(i.df6))
    df7=pd.DataFrame(pickle.loads(i.df7))
    
    df_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7]
    df_names = ['df1', 'df2', 'df3', 'df4', 'df5', 'df6', 'df7']
    
    df_dict = dict(zip(df_names, df_list))

print(df1.columns)
```

When i execute this code in jupyter notebooki have no problems and i get the right column names for the dataframes, but if i execute in cmd as python main.py, i dont get the right columns, instead the first row of the data is set as the columns.
How could i solve this?

I have checked the version of python, pandas, sqlalchemy and pickle on jupyter notebook and my script with:

```
print('pandas',pd.__version__)
print('sqlalchemy',sqlalchemy.__version__)
print('python',python_version())
print('pickle',pickle.format_version)
```

And i get the same version on both:

```
pandas 2.1.0
sqlalchemy 2.0.21
python 3.9.13
pickle 4.0
```

Comment: You should first check all the version information of the packages and Python used, in your standalone program and in the notebook: Python, SQLAlchemy, Pandas; print the version numbers directly in the code. That way, you know that at least you're dealing with the same things (it's too often that running a Jupyter notebook turns out to be using a different Python kernel, and different packages, creating different results).

Comment: @9769953 i edited my question with the version of python pandas and sqlalchemy, and both have the same versions

Comment: What's the result of, say, `print(pickle.loads(i.df1))`? And `print(type(pickle.loads(i.df1)))`? The first-row problem sounds as if `pd.DataFrame` reads its argument as a TextIO object or something like, i.e, it parses its input, instead of copying a dataframe. (You may have to do some more debugging, using a debugger or just printing out values and types of important variables.)

Comment: Since you're only printing `df1.columns`, does removing all other dataframes, and the `df_list`, `df_names` and `df_dict` lines, make a difference? You'll want to create a *minimal* toy example to debug your problem.